# How to delay loading first View Controller?

Tags: ios

I want to delay loading First view controller until a function in AppDelegate is finished. The function should get ready some data for first view controller. But now, the first view loads without the data which should be prepared by function in AppDelegate

What is recommend way or example? please.

Answer (score 1):

Should you maybe move the code that gets the data ready to the viewControllers "viewDidLoad" method?

This method gets called after the view controller goes into memory and the elements are accessible, but before it actually becomes visible. Any processing you do here will have to complete before the content shows, and is where I put methods which get things from server etc.

If the processing takes a long time, then also good to use a spinner to let user know something's happening, because where nothing will show until the processing is done, the user might think it hung.

Answer (score 0):

One method for delaying the creation of objects until they're referenced is called a lazy init. In objective-c you can accomplish this by overriding the property's getter. Here's a snippet:

Assuming:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSObject *someObject;
```

You can implement as

```
- (NSObject *)someObject {
    if (!_someObject) {
        _someObject = [NSObject new];
    }
    return _someObject;
}
```

In this way, someObject is only created when it is first referenced. Hope this helps!